# Android: How to send and receive data through SMS messages

Tags: android, sms

I want to send some data (NOT MULTIMEDIA) through an SMS message in Android. Can this be done? I just want to send a very small amount of data from one phone to another, as XML or something.

Comment: XML isn't a very efficient use of the limited character count for SMS, but that doesn't really affect your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this would be by using sendDataMessage from SmsManager class.
Here's a little code (SMSSender):

```
SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsMgr.sendDataMessage(phoneNumber, null,
            (short) myApplicationPort, messageString.getBytes(), sentIntent, deliveryIntent);
```

Here's another little code (SMSReceiver):

```
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length];

        // getting SMS information from PDU
        for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
        }

        for (SmsMessage currentMessage : messages) {
            if (!currentMessage.isStatusReportMessage()) {

                String messageBody = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    byte[] messageByteArray = currentMessage.getPdu();

                    // skipping PDU header, keeping only message body
                    int x = 1 + messageByteArray[0] + 19 + 7;

// I'm not sure about this last line, as I'm not converting the bytes back to string, so test it out
                    String realMessage = new String(messageByteArray, x, messageByteArray.length-x);
```

Here's what you should add to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
     <data android:scheme="sms" />
     <data android:host="localhost" />
     <data android:port="12345" /><!-- this number should be the same as the `myApplicationPort` from above!!! -->
   </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks Viktor, looks good. But, will this cause the receiver of the message to display a popup asking it which application it wants to handle the message, or is it received silently in the background?

Comment: It is used silently, meaning only one application should listen for messages on one port.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question I'd say you can send ANY kind of text data like XML, JSON strings or whatever through SMS. You could for example identify your data messages on the receiver by a specific hash that could be a part of the content. The receiver should be listening for the SMS_RECEIVED intent.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
```

This way you could grab the data and delete the message after that from the message store so it wouldn't show up in the conversation.